# How do I translate a pattern like "Tap to enter comment"?

Tags: translation

I find it difficult to translate short software GUI instructional pieces like:

- Tap to enter comment
- Press here to talk
- Sign in to continue

Should I put it like:

- タップしてコメントを入力
- or must it be: ボタンをタップして、コメントを入力します
- or コメントを入力するをタップします（してください）
- or something else?

Comment: Additional context would be helpful. Is this for tablet software?

Comment: Yes, this is for software GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the examples you have are fine.  I would personally use `には` (In order to ~X, ...).  Also note that GUI actions often leave off the `する／します` when it is implied.  (Further note:  I think `タッチ` or `クリック` might be used more than `タップ`.)

- コメントを入力するには、タッチしてください
- (通話／録音)するには、こちらをクリック　－　Not sure of the exact meaning you want for "talk" without some context.
- 続けるにはログイン（してください）